# How to synchronize database contents between different databases?

Tags: database, synchronization, replication

I want to create a system where I will have multiple databases.

I'm thinking about the way how to transfer data between them.

One of the databases contains some Data (f.e. Adresses of Persons). This database will exist in several locations; f.e. a shop. And in each individual shop there will of course be information about different Persons in the shops database.

I also want to create one large master-database which should contain the data about all the persons stored in all the smaller databases from all those shops.

I was thinking about creating an application which pulls the data from the smaller databases and transfers it via TCP/IP to a server-application at the master-database, where it is stored for each shop individually.

But when I did some research about synchronising data throughout different databases I found out about something called "Replicatiton". Is this the better way to do this? Or is that meant for other things and cannot be applied in my scenario?

Further information:

The System will rely on Windows Operating system and will use MySQL as a dbms.
The Database will also be accessed via .net Entity Framework.

Greetings,

Tim

Comment: Two different rdbms? or flat file systmes?

Comment: this is a tough question to truly answer, because there are a lot of questions that need to be answered.  what operating systems will you be using, what data systems will you be using, where are the different sites located, etc.

Comment: rdbms? Im talking about Databases, like MySQL or MSSQL.

Comment: okay I added further information about the target software environment